# am I getting out of the fold of Islam?

Tags: practical-islam, shirk, kufr, waswasa, doubts

As Salamu Alaikum
I'm a music composer and sound effects creator, and I mostly do
freelance work in music and sound effects design. I will leave this
field permanently after I learn some halal skills such as programming.
but for now, I'm holding music because I'm from a third-world country,
my family is poor, and I have a big responsibility to feed my family
(my father, mother, and brother). but I have a plan to leave this
music field.

I have been getting a serious question in my mind that even I can't sleep.
Much of my music and sound effects have been sold to many game
developers and game companies. The game company uses my music and
sound effects in their game. Among those games, there is some fantasy
game that has some shirk and kufr. Example:- If the game character is
dead they can be revived by using the magic to bring the character
back to life. My music and sound effect is used in these kinds of
games. My question is, am I getting out of the fold of Islam that my
music and sound effect is used in those kinds of games even though I
know it?
Do note that I don't believe in any kind of fantasy things in these games.

Answer (score 0):

Wa asalam alikum brother/sister The music industry is filled with filth and dirt and haram.
Music can influence the brain. Music takes you to a new reality so if you are always listening you are so used to a high that when you stand in prayer you find it boring and dead because there is no music as your mind does not like old boring reality._______________________________
May Allah (swt) bless all muslim and May Allah (swt) guide all muslims
Inshallah you can find a better job  for you and your family
Inshallah you will learn programming